# my android Phone(internal storage) doesn't show up or mount when connected via USB cable to laptop but other flash drives are showing up

Tags: usb, mount, android

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and my phone does not show up on my laptop when connected via a USB cable it doesn't show up either on the left side dock or in the files application and other USB drives are appearing on my files application but the phone storage is not there
how do I transfer files from my phone to my laptop

it does not show the phone storage/drive when I run `sudo fdisk -l` or in Drives application but when I run `lsusb` it shows some new ID

[Running `lsusb` before and after connecting phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSHfb.png)

[shows my phone company name and some other details when I run `usb-devices` when connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4mCq.png)

Comment: Dumb question (maybe): What option have you selected **in the phone** after connecting?

Comment: i've tried filer transfer,transfer photos(ptp), and charging

Comment: Well, "charging" as in in "charging only" is self-explanatory and didn't need to be tested for this issue because *not* mounting is the expected behavior. Now, both MTP and PTP should. Have you tried the phone in another computer and confirmed it works as expected? If so, try rebooting it before trying again in this one. Next make sure `mpt-tools` is installed (reinstall just to be sure).

Comment: yes i have tried installing and reinstalling `mtp-tools` and android adb and my phone mounts perfectly on windows OS and I've tried different phones too. please help find a way

Answer (score 0):

i have an android phone and two seemingly identical cables.
The phone works perfectly with one cable but not with the other.
Both cables work okay with other devices.
Only difference I can see is that, one cable has the USB bus symbol on the plugs the other does not. The one with the USB symbol on it works.
Might help.
I am simply saying it could be a cable problem as I have experienced.

Comment: yes you're right, I've tried different phones and cables none of them mounted, I belive  it is an issue with my software